# Does SharedPreference needs time to sync data?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store data into *SharedPreference* in a loop, but I'm getting this error as result :

```
 D/SharedPreferencesImpl: Time required to fsync /data/user/0/pacjakename/shared_prefs/shared.xml: [<1: 0, <2: 0, <4: 0, <8: 0, <16: 0, <32: 0, <64: 0, <128: 1, <256: 0, <512: 2, <1024: 0, <2048: 0, <4096: 0, <8192: 0, <16384: 0, >=16384: 0]
```

Here is How I store data:

```
  public void savePromotions(RequestResponse requestResponse) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("promotions", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(requestResponse);
    editor.putString("promotions", json).apply();
}
```

Is shared-preference required time to store data?

Or what is this message for?

Comment: please show us your code. If you use commit and you store large amount of data, then the editor blocks the current thread. Maybe consider using apply (which stores the data asynchronously)?

Comment: @peshkira updated

Comment: It is just a debug log: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#829

Comment: This log is written with level DEBUG, unlikely it is really an error message.

Comment: Should I care for this message so?

Comment: The answer to is no, don't need to care about that message.

Comment: I think you should care since it may cause troubles later.
How about calling first putString(...) multiple times and then calling apply() just once at the end of your loop?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be calling that in a loop? That method only writes to the `"promotions"` key, so it would just be repeatedly overwriting that value, and only the last one would persist.